# 1980's Stand Alone Serial (RS232) Spool File

Tags: identify-this-peripheral

It was

- a device the size of a Hayes Smart Modem.
- it had two RS232 ports, one In, one Out
- and 256K of memory (I think, might have been less).

It was a cunning little tool - plugged between a PC and a printer it allowed the user to print and not have to take a 10 minute break while the PC twiddled its thumbs.

Can anyone identify the device and its manufacturer?

Comment: Since there have been dozend s inf not more than 100 devices which this description covers, identifying it without further (substantial) information like a photo or a manual will be practical impossible.

Comment: Was even plans for one in Ciarcia's Circuit Cellar Volume 5 : [The Smartspooler](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Ciarcia_s_Circuit_Cellar/fBuiNpYlyHcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA131&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: There were plenty of these. And in addition to serial/serial, there were also parallel/parallel and even serial/parallel and parallel/serial.

Comment: That's why I'm asking - I don't have a manual or a photo - I don't want to build one - I just want to see one ( or many ) and finish my "story".

Comment: @user3840170 in a non-multitasking system, once you started printing your system would be locked up until the software finished printing.  This would often be limited by the speed of the printer itself.

Comment: @user3840170 It's a Printer Buffer. Classic systems, including the PC with DOS 1.0, can't buffer printer output. At the same time Printers didn't have arge buffers. Usually just a few lines. So when a program was printing more than that, the interface was slowed down to the printing speed, the computer blocked. Ram-Buffers like today were not really possible with the small RAM sizes So external print buffers having their own 16..256 KiB RAM became a thing. IBM added the Print Utility to DOS 2.0, but it needed the output to be stored on disk first. So print buffers were still helpful.

Comment: Would you mind editing the question to clarify what ‘allowed the user to print and not have to take a 10 minute break while the PC twiddled its thumbs’ refers to?

Answer (score 9):

A quick search found one example [here](https://www.cablesdirect.com/store/p/3663.aspx):

[image: Buffer]

This one was marketed specifically for plotters, which makes a lot of sense as plotting can take a *long* time for a single page.

A search on eBay for *printer buffer* brings up plenty. Some brands listed there, most of which I recognize from ye olden times, include:

- Quadram Microfazer
- Buffalo
- Hayes (yes, that one is *exactly* the size of a Hayes modem)
- Extended Systems
- Practical Peripherals Microbuffer